# How can I capture errors and exceptions data from frontend response to django to add more context

Tags: django, reactjs, error-handling, sentry

I want to receive some parameters with my error capture on django when something wrong on the front-end

I have react frontend running on a django backend. Sentry is been used to capture errors and report.

In settings.py:

```py
SENTRY_DSN = os.environ.get("SENTRY_DSN")
if SENTRY_DSN:
    sentry_sdk.init(
        dsn=SENTRY_DSN,
        integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
        environment=ENVIRONMENT,
        release=os.environ.get("HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION")
        or "HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION not set",
    )
    with configure_scope() as scope:
        scope.user = {"user": "broken lol"}
```

This is reporting the errors from entire app.

However, I want to add user ids to error Sentry reports. To do that I need to capture the response from frontend and somehow get that into settings.py and replace the `"broken lol"` string with `UserId`

Answer (score 2):

To capture user IDs from Django's user objects, set `init(..., send_default_pii=True)`. We do not have this as default because this can be a footgun for privacy.

Comment: yeah, privacy is important for me as well. Any other approach can you recommend? It doesn't have to be done on this particular file, If its best I can add this to every exception too. I just don't know the best way

Comment: @NaimMustafa There are infinite approaches, but what problem with `send_default_pii=True` do you want to solve?